# Sync issue with avconv

Tags: streaming, avconv, video-streaming, audio-sync

I am screen casting and cannot get the audio and video to sync. I believe it is the video that is advancing because the audio seems to be running fine. The command I am using is:

```
avconv -f pulse -b:a 192k -q:a 10 -g 0 -ac 2 -i alsa_input.pci-0000_00_14.2.analog-stereo -f x11grab -r 30 -q:v 0 -g 0 -s 1600x900 -i :0.0 -c:v huffyuv -c:a aac -strict experimental test.avi
```

This isn't the only command I have used but it is the closest one to working. What can I do to get these to sync.

Ok... It is definitely the video. Its skips forward every few seconds.

Answer (score 1):

After looking at the system resources on the system monitor application, it was obvious that the computer could not keep up with the screen capture.

This solution was something I did not want. I reduced the frame rate to about 13 fps and it was syncing much better but I lost all that frame rate! libx264 was not efficient enough to make it much better. If anybody else has this problem, check the system resources and you will probably find that the CPU is being run up to 100%.